# How to know if code made by a third party runs on release

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Can I know if a piece of code like `print`, `assert`, `log_os` etc compiles on DEBUG only besides looking at documentation, as it is often incomplete and the implementation is not public?

If not, is my only solution to call every code that is for debug purposes between compiler preprocessors like this:

```
#if DEBUG
assert(true)
print("Hello")
#endif
```

I want to make sure that the code is not present at all for safety and performance reasons.

Will a code like this be optimised by the compiler and removed completely on release, or will it have some assembly left like a jump to a function that is empty:

```
func DebugOnlyPrint(message: String) {
#if DEBUG
print(message)
#endif
}
```

Comment: There should be no traces left in the generated code.

Answer (score 2):

To see the outputs run the release version and then in Xcode go to `Window -> Devices` (or press cmd+shift+2).

Now connect an iOS device to the Mac and do > `View Device Logs` and you'll see all the output.